# Ubuntu command is repeated/shown in the next line everytime I enter a command

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my WSL/Bash, whenever I type any command, it is repeated/shown in the very next line before being executed.

E.g. If I I typed/commanded a useless/non-existing command, it'd show the same 'command' or 'words' in the next line and then will show the prompt again in the 3rd line. If I typed 'ls', then before showing the file list, it'll show/return 'ls' written in the very next line (and then show the real list of files at the current location).

How can I stop this behavior? (Don't know how was it started anyhow?!)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have debugging turned on.  Try this command and see what happens:

```
set +x # This turns off debugging.
```

If this fix the problem, you'll need to check your init files to find out where it is turned on then remove the code.

From the help file:

```
-x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
```

To view the complete help of set command, use `help set`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But after I turned off my pc on yesterday, and switched on today, the problem auto went away. 
Now unfortunately I can't diagnose if this command would have helped (though I'm sure, it would). 
And I'm very much inclined to test this command anyway, but am afraid lest I should switch on something unwanted.
Thanks.